# How to get value of property on action model on OnActionExecuted

Tags: .net-core, action-filter, onactionexecuted

I need to run some code after action executed using **ActionFilter** based on a property in the action Model, How to get a value of the property inside OnActionExecuted?

Model

```
public class Profile
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Action

```
public BotProfileDTO Update(Profile profile)
{

}
```

Action Filter

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
       //How to get profile Id here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot inside `context`, so if you poke around inside it you'll find all sorts of useful things.

In your case, I think what you want lives in `context.ActionParameters` which is a collection of the parameters passed to the controller endpoint.  If you know that your method should always receive one and only one parameter, you could access it with something like:

`var myId = (context.ActionParameters.Single().Value as Profile).Id`

All typical notes and caveats regarding Single() and casting apply here, so make sure you grab the parameter from the collection in the right way for your case.